# Как реализовать хранение данных пользователя на удаленном сервере через API?

Tags: php, java, android, mysql, firebase-android

Имеется **backend** для **android** приложения (**PHP + MySQL**) и API  с помощью которой подтягиваются данные в это приложение. Реализована авторизация в приложении посредством **Firebase Auth** (через Google провайдера).

В качестве личных данных пользователя получаю **email** и **токен** (уникальный идентификатор).

Есть база данных **MySQL**, которая необходима для работы веб-приложения, и с которой собственно отдаются необходимые данные по **GET** запросам.

1) Как лучше реализовать хранение различных данных пользователя в mySQL базе, посредством обращения к **API**?

2) Достаточно ли безопасно использовать **token**, получаемый при авторизации через Google , чтобы исключить возможность подбора и получения данных через API?

3) Как защитить API от запросов из вне? (несанкционированное использование за пределом android приложения). Если использовать тоже какой-либо токен, где его хранить в приложении? Ведь всё очень легко "разбирается и достается".

**P.S:** Авторизация в приложении не является обязательной и подразумевается, что **API** будет отдавать "общие данные" вне зависимости, авторизовался пользователь или нет.

Comment: Если Java (в списке тегов есть), то см. JWT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) используйте Орм.
2) безопасно
3) если не ошибаюсь это про  "cors доменные запросы".хранить нужно в  localStorage/SessionStorage. токен-это ключ  от дома, его можно смотреть , но другим не давать.

Comment: цитата: токен-это ключ от дома, его можно смотреть , но другим не давать. ==

то есть узнав токен, нельзя использовать API в своих целях, в своих приложениях и т.д ?